# Replace occurrences of one dataset in another

Tags: r, powerbi

I have a dataset called Messages that contains C# errors. I have a 2nd dataset called Usernames that contains a list of usernames. I want to remove occurrences of any username from messages. No message should have more then 1 occurance of username. I thought I could do this with gsubfn, but it output all NULLs. Can someone set me straight on the best way to do this?

```
usrNm <- c(dataset2$username)
stripUsername <- function(x) {gsubfn(usrNm,'',x)}
noUsernames <- within(dataset,{Message=stripUsername(dataset$Message)})
```

```
+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+    +--------------+
| Message                          | Expected output                  |    | Username     |
+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+    +--------------+
| User: Mary.Jane sent bad data    | User:  sent bad data             |    | Mary.Jane    |
+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+    +--------------+
| Error occurred in System.Module. | Error occurred in System.Module. |    | Robert.Frost |
+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+    +--------------+
| Hello, world!                    | Hello, world!                    |    | BB.Wolf      |
+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+    +--------------+
| Tracing request by Robert.Frost! | Tracing request by !             |
+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
library(stringi)

stri_replace_all_fixed(dataset$Message, dataset2$Username, '', vectorize_all = FALSE)
```

**Output**

```
[1] "User:  sent bad data"             "Error occurred in System.Module."
[3] "Hello, world!"                    "Tracing request by !"
```

**Data**

```
dataset <- data.frame(
  Message = c("User: Mary.Jane sent bad data", "Error occurred in System.Module.", "Hello, world!", "Tracing request by Robert.Frost!"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

dataset2 <- data.frame(
  Username = c("Mary.Jane", "Robert.Frost", "BB.Wolf")
)
```